# The fractional energy loss of charged particle per radiation length

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics

I have a hard time understanding the "fractional energy loss" of the charged particle, as shown in the figure below.

[image]

The figure usually has a caption that goes like this: "Fractional energy loss per radiation length as a function of electron or positron energy in lead," but why I do not fathom is at $\frac{1}{E}\frac{dE}{dx} = 1$, it seems like the particle is losing all of its energy at ~7MeV by ionisation. Therefore, I would not expect the other contributions will happen. However, the diagram seems to suggest that even at very low energy we still have losses through other processes and most bizarrely the "fractional loss" through ionisation even went greater than 1 at very low energy. What does this even mean? Is it trying to say that the ionisation is "relatively higher" than the other processes, and the fraction of all the processes is not normalised to 1?

Source: https://cds.cern.ch/record/2315747/

Comment: Note that this figure is actually from [the "interactions with matter" chapter of the Particle Data Group's biannual review](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2023/reviews/experimental_methods_and_colliders.html); it's currently figure 34.11, but it gets renumbered between editions.

Answer (score 0):

The term $\frac {dE}{dx}/E$ has units of 1/Length, or fractional energy lost per unit of length. If the length unit, like cm or m, is large compared to the actual distance traveled by the charge, then it wouldn't lose all its energy over the range of interest.  I would have to read the paper in detail to say more.

It's kind of like defining the Ampere as the charge producing 1 Newton between two wires one meter apart. You would never actually set up a measurement apparatus with wires 1 m apart and try to measure 1 N.  It would be more on the order of mm.  Just like you would never try to measure light speed with detectors that are 299,792,458 m apart.

Comment: The paper and the original source of the diagram said nothing about the distance travelled. Even if we are considering what you said, the fact that the fractional loss is greater than the total incoming energy E is still not explained when the energy is small, i.e. around 5MeV. At that energy, I would expect the electrons to lose energy whole by ionisation, so the groh should plateau at y=1 for low energy, right?

Answer (score 0):

The curve which troubles you is the "ionization" curve.  However, if you send a fast electron into matter, where it ionizes an atom, you now have *two* fast electrons, each with about half of the initial energy. Electrons more energetic than 1 MeV can also lose energy by electron-positron pair creation.  I think the way to interpret this figure is that the energy is lost by *any particular* electron on length scales shorter than the radiation length of the entire shower. For some links, see [this related answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/646780/44126).

Comment: Thank you for adding a link to the original source of the diagram. I think you made a typo for the electron more than 1Mev--shouldn't that be a photon? Also, even if we have two fast electrons, their energy should be E or less than E, right? But the graph seemed like implying that that the "fractional loss is greater than E, say around 1.2E at 5MeV. Also, what do you mean by the radiation length of the shower? Is that the shower depth?

Comment: I guess you have to have a 1 MeV bremsstrahlung photon, but the phase space for those starts with 1MeV electrons. I think we mean roughly the same thing by "shower depth" and "radiation length"; the energy-loss process is generally exponential, so the best "length" parameter is a $e$-folding distance. What I am suggesting is that a 1 MeV electron, at the point in the shower where half the energy has been absorbed, might have become twenty electrons with an average energy of 25 MeV each. I'm not sure, though. Consider following the references in the PDG.